# jest spies on component functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I create a jest spy to test my component function with expecting the function will be called. However, it seems not to be called.

This is my test:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
  import SideNavBar from '../SideNavBar';
  test('Should call mock function when clicking NavBar button', () => {
    const openNavSpy = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<SideNavBar openNav={openNavSpy} />);
    wrapper.find('i').simulate('click');
    expect(openNavSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

This is my some related code from SideNavBar:

```
openNav = () => {
    if (this.mySidenav) {
      this.mySidenav.style.width = '360px';
    }
  };
....
 <i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.openNav} />
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.openNav` is referencing the classes `openNav` and not the spy prop that you pass in through `SideBarNav` from your test.

```
test('Should call mock function when clicking NavBar button', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SideNavBar />);
    const openNavSpy = jest.fn();

    wrapper.instance().openNav = openNavSpy;

    wrapper.find('i').simulate('click');

    expect(openNavSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Instead of testing that `openNav` was called why don't you test that `mySideNav`'s width was set instead.
This would be better because we actually don't care that `openNav` was called on click we only care that the width was set on click.

```
test('Should set the side nav width to 360px', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SideNavBar />);

    wrapper.find('i').simulate('click');

    const sideNav = wrapper.instance().mySidenav;

    expect(sideNav.style.width).toBe('360px');
});
```